# Unable to read the json file using python

Tags: python, json, mongodb

i am trying to read a json file that is the input for Mongodb. if i can edit a single record as a valid jason i am able to do so. but when i am trying to read the entire file, i am not able to do it. it shows me error.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBAtp.gif.)

I have done a base code like given below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json 
# comment : Importing the json file to read;
database = "new 2.json"
data = json.loads(open(database).read())

# Comment : Variable Declaration;

# Comment : Display the json values;
for key,value in data.iteritems():
    if 'patient_id' == key:
        print("key: {0} | value: {1}".format(key, value))
    if 'name' == key:
        print("key: {0} | value: {1}".format(key, value))
    if 'age' == key:
        print("key: {0} | value: {1}".format(key, value))
    if 'gender' == key:
        print("key: {0} | value: {1}".format(key, value))
# for key,value in data.iteritems():
    if 'address' == key:
        print("key: {0} | value: {1}".format(key, value))
    # if 'labRecords' == key:
        # print("key: {0} | value: {1}".format(key, value))
```

i am able to print the data for a single record, that i have corrected into a proper json file.
but for the others i need to modify all the records.
is there any way to do it???

Comment: Did you verify that your `json` is valid? You can do this with any `json` verifier online.

Comment: i think u should decode the json with `json.loads(open(database).read().decode('utf-8'))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
import json
with open("json_data.json", mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    print(data)
```

**json_data.json**

```
 {
  "hello": 11,
  "world": 22,
  "json": 33
}
```

**output**

```
{'hello': 11, 'world': 22, 'json': 33}
```

make sure your `json` format data is ok. and check first you get the output as you want. and than you can proceed your further work.

Comment: How is this any different than my answer?

Comment: @Jebby, sounds good and you are not checking the `encoding` format. But your answer is cool. :) and thanks putting -1 on my Ans. :P

Comment: i tried with a single record in json file. it seems to work. but the original file is not in json format i guess. it looks like a json file but actually not, even the json converter is showing error.i am using the json file which is input to mongodb. is there any option for convering the wrong json file to a correct one using python???

Comment: you may check this site https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ where the syntax error by putting your json data. And one thing if the answer seems to helpful than putting upvote or accepting you can help others. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the second parameter to `open` which should be one of either:

`a`, `r`, `w`, `rb`, or `wb`

With the file `test.json` in the working directory, this works for me:

### Test.json

```
{
  "foo": 1,
  "bar": 2,
  "baz": 3
}
```

### Python script:

```
import json

with open("test.json", "rb") as f:
    data = json.load(f)


for key, value in data.items():
    print(key, value)
```

### Output:

```
foo 1
bar 2
baz 3
```

Comment: what is the rb used for ? can you please let me know?

Comment: `rb` means "read this file in binary mode"
`wb` means "write to this file in binary mode"

This is useful when you need to deal with bytes-like objects.